# How can I give each ng-model in an ng-repeat a unique identifier?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with multiple AngularUI sliders, and a span displaying the value of each slider with an ng-bind. It looks something like this:

```
   <div class="formitem" ng-repeat="food in foodlist" >
     <div ui-slider="{range: 'min'}" min="0" max="{{ unit.max }}" ng-model="demoVals.slider" class="food-slider" >
      <div class="begin">1</div>
      <div class="end"> {{ unit.max }} {{ food.uid }}  </div>
    </div>
    <span ng-bind="demoVals.slider"></span>
   </div>
```

I want the ng-model to be unique for each food item, so something like `demoVals.slider57`, where 57 is the output of `{{ food.uid }}`. I can get `{{ food.uid }}` to print out in the template just fine, but if I try to add it to the ng-model or ng-bind, I just get this:

```
 ng-model="demoVals.slider[food.uid]"
```

How can I add the food.uid to the ng-model of each food item?

Comment: ng-model doesn't accept expression as it needs to map to a scope object. Have you tried $index?

Comment: Not sure how to achieve that but did you consider making them elements of an array instead?

Comment: create a demo, likely other ways either by directive, or slider callbacks and some traversing you can do whatever it is you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be a good architectural choice to use individual elements instead of using an array. You should really try to switch to put your slider values into an array.

However, you can use some controller function to achieve what you want, although it is rather ugly. Within your `ng-repeat` you can bind to a function

```
<div ng-bind="test(food.uid)"></div>
```

with the function being

```
$scope.test = function test(v) {
        var t = $scope.$eval("demoVals.slider" + v);
        return t;
      };
```

Comment: I think you are correct, that it is not a good architectural choice. I was trying to work around a scope issue that is probably better solved by solving the scope issue itself. But this is marked as correct as it shows me how I could have solved the question asked. Here's my updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766957/scope-variable-output-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `food.uid` property to demoVals for each iteration. This brings the need to execute js code on each iteration. That can be only be done (IMHO)in a directive.

So here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeestX?p=preview)

Here is how you should modify your html ( notice the `repeat-directive` ... directive :)

```
 <div class="formitem" ng-repeat="food in foodlist" repeat-directive>
 <div ui-slider="{range: 'min'}" min="0" max="{{ unit.max }}" ng-model="demoVals.slider" class="food-slider" >
  <div class="begin">1</div>
  <div class="end"> {{ unit.max }} {{ food.uid }}  </div>
</div>
<span ng-bind="demoVals.slider"></span>
```

here is the code for the direective that will be executed on every iteration:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
             .directive ('repeatDirective',function () {
                                           return {
                                              restrict: 'A',
                                              link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                                                console.log('linking directive ',scope.demoVals)
                                                 if (scope.food){
                                                   // you have a value for food
                                                   // you can add it as an attribute to demoVals
                                                   scope.demoVals['prop'+scope.food.uid] = scope.food.name;
                                                 }}
                                           }
                                          });
```