# Scope & variable output in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My quest: a page of sliders, made with an ng-repeat through a JSON file. Spans showing the value of each slider. An input showing `(value of the slider * a grams value per selected unit)`.

[Here's my Plunkr with multiple sliders, each with a selection of 2 food values.](http://plnkr.co/edit/WnjcrjG0NiCTUGtXA6PP?p=preview)

The span showing the output of the slider should initialise at 0. My first problem is, if I initialise it at 0 in the main controller as shown in a previous question, then this changes the scope of the slider `demoVals.slider` so that all sliders on the page now operate in unison:

```
 //assign initial values
  $scope.demoVals = {};
  $scope.demoVals.slider = 0;
```

If you comment out those lines, each slider can now be operated individually again.

I thought I could solve this by assigning a unique identifier to the ng-model & ng-bind of each slider & its output, but is there a better way to limit the scope so that the initialisation is happening individually for each ng-repeat?

My next problem is trying to call a multiplication function on the value of the output: how can I pass the grams unit selected (accessible in the template as `{{ unit-grams }}`) to the controller, and have the result returned as the value of the `input`?

```
   //calculate weight
   $scope.$watch('demoVals.slider', function (newVal) {
        if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
          $scope.calculated = newVal * 3.14159; //an arbitrary number that I want to be the variable unit.grams
        } 
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you actually tried to do to solve this (what do you mean by "by assigning a unique identifier to the ng-model & ng-bind of each slider & its output"?), but if you want separate values for each food slider, it should also be an element of the food object as it belong to this object in nature.

Instead of using `demoVals.slider` use e.g. `food.slider`. You can also initialize this using `ng-init`, i.e. `ng-init="food.slider=0;"`

I updated the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CbkSZpzoqXwcMkV1EDdp?p=preview

However, it seems like a good idea to separate all this into its own food controller. This way you could process each `food` item in its own scope.

Comment: Wow, great- thank you for the working example. Should I also move the `ng-init="unit = food.unit[0]"` to the ng-repeat, where you have moved the other initialisations in your demo? I can't seem to get the select lists to initialise with the first option selected now.

Comment: Found it: `food.unit.selected = food.unit[0]"` in the ng-repeat. Thanks again for the working demo!